# A visual webpage editing tool that can support asp.net web forms tags

Tags: asp.net, html, editor, wysiwyg, html-editor

I've been looking hard to find a web page editor that can let me visually edit an already-designed asp.net web form page. for the whole period, I've made my page designs with Dreamweaver (now I'm using Dreamweaver CS4) and transfered my designs to Visual Studio 2010 to make asp.net pages from that template. Table editing feature for web forms in Visual Studio is really annoying and by trying to change a column width, the table structure is corrupted and VS decides to change everything on that table (compare it with Dreamweaver which only changes those two columns which their border is changed instead of the whole columns of that table).

Unfortunately Dreamweaver does not recognize the asp.net tags syntax and because of that it can not properly render them in design mode. I want to know if you know any tool (preferably non-Microsoft tool) that can let me open an asp.net web form in it and edit the page elements visually without side effects that Visual Studio causes to my page design. (I use HTML tables for arranging my page elements.)

By the way I looked at this link:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTML_editors

but after opening all the visual editors web pages, I did not find any tool that supports ASP.net tags.

Comment: Do you know about firebug? it is available in all the browsers. try to use that it will definitely help you...

Comment: Why are you using tables?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html

Comment: @raman: I'm already using firebug.

Comment: @Farshid there is option to edit the html by using that you can do that and from there you can copy paste the final output.

Answer (score 4):

Is there a particular reason that though you are working on a Microsoft platform that you don't want to use a Microsoft editor?

MS provides two free tools that may help you:

- [Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-products)
- [Web Matrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/)

Also, I highly recommend using CSS classes to set widths on ASP.NET generated tables/columns. (Rather than using the styling attributes for those ASP.NET controls.)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry but the WYSIWYG editor of all MS tools since Visual Studio.net, 2005, 2008, 2010, VWD and the version of Expression Web (v. 4 of it), all handle table manipulation terribly. That's why I always first make HTML code using dreamweaver and then move the page structure to VS to make it an ASP.net website.

Comment: @Farshid What do you mean by "...all handle table manipulation terribly"?

Comment: How have you been using WYSIWYGs for the last 7 years and still choose to use them over just writing your HTML?

Comment: For clarification: I use CSS for storing properties of my elements totally. but when I need to do things on very complicated layouts, I do not want to restart calculating some terribly nested elements from scratch and instead of that, I want to use a good-workinggraphical editor for modifying small portions of my layout. Why I don't use microsoft tools? test yourself! make a new aspx page. put a table on it, consisting of for example 5 or 6 rows and columns, make some columns wider than others and try to modify the column width without other columns getting modified.

Comment: @Farshid, I've been developing in Visual Studio for the past 8 years. I think the key is to not rely too much on the asp.net controls designed to make front-end work easier. I focus on getting ASP.NET to output the markup I want, then I can do what I need to with CSS & JavaScript. So, no data-grids, etc. Avoiding the bad parts of ASP.NET gets even easier with ASP.NET MVC. Cheers.

Comment: @Kevin:I'm not using VS for design, I really know that how awful is the development experience with VS. I just needed it for cases where a minor modification is required and I can't return it back to the (always-correctly-working) dreamweaver because DW does not support asp.net tags.

Comment: +1 to Kevin and Lawrence, I've been using VS for a couple of years, but just recently moved into web dev, and I don't even use the toolbox for most controls, just type out the ASP.NET control information right there. @Farshid, why aren't you just typing the HTML/CSS out? Dreamweaver is a huge crutch. On top of that, it spits out bloated code with most things.

Comment: @Kevin: Dear Kevin, thanks but your answer is not useful to me at all because at my question I clarified that Visual Studio has serious problems in the scenario I want to use. The tools your told are essentially the same as VS and I've tested them myself and they have that problem also.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.Editor`.
Put the DLL in your project and than put in the page, than you can edit.
Create some logic to view and edit with some permission, and your page will have content editable.

Comment: Seems like you have not realized the question.